# DOM manipulation questions

Tags: javascript, php, html, dom

i've succesfully uploaded my image to database, my code :

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $name = $_POST["inputEntryName"];
    $picture_tmp = $_FILES['inputFile']['tmp_name'];
    $picture_name = $_FILES['inputFile']['name'];
    $picture_type = $_FILES['inputFile']['type'];
    $desc = $_POST["desc"];
    $path = "upload/". $picture_name;

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $picture_name)){
        echo $picture_name . " already exists. ";
    }
    else{
        if(move_uploaded_file($picture_tmp,$path)){
            require_once "database.php";
            $db = new Database();
            $insQuery = "insert into image(name,image,description) values('".$picture_tmp."','".$path."','".$desc."')";
            $result = $db->query($insQuery);
            echo "File successfully uploaded!";
        }
        else{
            echo "File is not uploaded.";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

i want to make a div for every image in my database something like this :

```
<name>
<image>
<description>
```

then i want to append those divs to my main container in index.php.
how can i do this ? is this dom manipulation or is there another way easier to achieve this ?

this is my testfunction :

Comment: How are you uploading the images? If it is via javascript the method would differ than if via a more traditional form submission.

Comment: i did it via traditional form submission as in the code above.

Comment: As it is the case that you use a standard form POST rather than Javascript there would appear to be no need for DOM manipulation using PHP or Javascript - simply generate the content at runtime using a query to retrieve the image details from the db ( for all images ) and loop through the recordset generating the desired html structure.

Comment: can you pls guide me how to ? 
i've edited the post including my function .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requested, a quick example to guide you display images after submitting the form and updating your db.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require_once 'database.php';

    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
        /* Perform any checks to ensure there is  file to proceess */

        /* Handle file upload */

        /* Insert record into db */
    }
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>File upload and image display</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- 
           by omitting the action, we automatically POST the form to the same page
           and is processed at the top of the script
        -->
        <form name='fileupload' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
            <!--
                Include all the fields & buttons required to upload file(s)
            -->
        </form>
        <!-- :: Display images :: -->
        <div id='images'>
        <?php
            /*
                This is slightly pseudo code because it is impossible to know the
                exact manner in which your `database` class works - mysql, mysqli
                or possibly pdo.
            */

            $sql='select `name`,`image`,`description` from `image`;';
            if( !$db ) $db = new Database;
            $res=$db->query( $sql );
            if( $res ){
                while( $rs=$res->fetch_object() ){
                    echo "
                    <div>
                        {$rs->name}
                        <img src='/path/to/images/{$rs->image}' alt='{$rs->description}' />
                        {$rs->description}
                    </div>";
                }
            }

            $db->close();
        ?>
        </div>
        <!-- :: End display images :: -->
    </body>
</html>
```

If this is not what you mean then please explain what it is you are trying to do - this should query the db and generat the necessary html

Comment: yes, this is what im looking for, just as you post the comment , i found out that i can return html in php code !!.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
// ... assuming that this is the array of the images
$arr = ...

for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $arr ); $i++ ) {

    echo "<h1>Name</h1>";
    echo "<img src=\"" . $arr[ $i ] . "\" />";
    echo "<p>Description</p>";

}
```

Here, you can get the names and the descriptions in the same way you get the images.

Comment: what im trying to do is to automatically make a div that contains all the variables and then append it to the main container.

how to do that with your code ?